# Как включить ориентацию экрана .portraitUpsideDown

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

#### Не могу добиться работы экрана в режиме .portraitUpsideDown.

В настройках target включены все четыре Supported interface orientations,
в plist тоже прописаны все четыре и для Iphone и для Ipad. Однако:

```
self.supportedInterfaceOrientations.contains(.portraitUpsideDown).description
```

Получен результат false:

```
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.portraitUpsideDown.rawValue
UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

Попытка повернуть экран вверх головой программно - не удалась.
Как включить (программно) возможность работы с данным положением ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Странно, видать баг Xcode. Значит пропишите в коде:

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    get {
        return .all
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, теперь заработало